# Using Get-MailboxDatabase to return archive database with smallest mailbox count?

Tags: exchange, powershell

I have a one liner PoSH command I use to return the smallest (by mailbox number) database, it works great...

```
Get-MailboxDatabase LIVE_* -Status | select Name,@{Name="NumberofUsers";Expression={(Get-Mailbox -resultsize unlimited -Database $_.name).Count}} | Sort -Property NumberofUsers | Select -ExpandProperty Name -First 1
```

I want to use this command to also return the smallest archive database by archive mailbox number count, how can this be done?

I tried...

```
Get-MailboxDatabase ARCHIVE_* -Status | select Name,@{Name="NumberofUsers";Expression={(Get-Mailbox -Archive resultsize unlimited -Database $_.name).Count}} | Sort -Property NumberofUsers | Select -ExpandProperty Name -First 1
```

Our archive mailbox databases have an ARCHIVE_ prefix which i've changed above, but it is not working, for each archive database the NumberofUsers value returned is 0.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks.

Comment: In your question, your archive command is missing the "-" before `-ResultSize`. Is that a typo, or was your command missing this as well?